# Why i'm unable to use path,fs import globally in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have problem with file module import that is why i'm unable to import them throughout my project

im getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined

**i have main.js import like below:**

```
const { electron,
    app, // Module to control application's life.
    BrowserWindow, // Module to create native browser window.
    Menu, // The menu class is used to create native menus that can be used as application menus and context menus.
    ipcMain, // The ipcMain module, when used in the main process, handles asynchronous and synchronous messages sent from a renderer process (web page).
    shell, // Module that provides functions related to desktop integration.
    globalShortcut // Module can register/unregister a global keyboard shortcut with the operating system so that you can customize the operations for various shortcuts.
    // Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
} = require('electron');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port','8315');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('host-rules','MAP * 127.0.0.1');
const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
```

**in my js file where i want to use path, fs:**

`usingfile.js`

```
   if (inElectron()){
        var {ipcRenderer} = require('electron'),
        remote = require('electron').remote; // Allows IPC with main process in Electron.

    var {path} = require('path');

    var {fs} = require('fs');


    }
```

**if i use use path or fs i will get above eror (`usingfile.js`)**

```
    var fileLoc = path.join(__dirname, 'folder/');
    var fileList = fs.readdirSync( fileLoc );
```

in the above line i get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no object or property `path` in the library `path` but that's what you are asking for, when you use this code:

```
var {path} = require('path');
```

The correct code is this:

```
if (inElectron()){
    var {ipcRenderer} = require('electron'),
    remote = require('electron').remote; // Allows IPC with main process in Electron.

    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
}
```